# Recover data from deleted custom field

Tags: apex, trigger

In my SF org, client was using "TOTAL (Currency)" Field from Year 2008 to 2013.
Due to some changes in the process, as they Old SF guy has removed the field and not saved the data.
Now they want to retrieve the data back into the same field. 
If anyone knows how to retrieve the data or SF will help me on this any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple places you can check for the data:
Setup > Data Management > Data Export if your company has been exporting and downloading the weekly data exports, you can look through the archived data to find the last point at which it was still in production.

Full Sandbox - if your Full sandbox is old enough, you can retrieve the data from the point in time when the sandbox was last refreshed.

If neither of those sources have the data you need, you can pay Salesforce to retrieve data, although it's very expensive.

Comment: @sachinkumar -- if there were analytic snapshots that snapped the deleted field, you may be able to recover from that source; you may also have excel workbooks created by your (sales) operations folks that could be used to reload

Comment: @AlwaysThinkin - in Schedule Data Export which format i need to select "Export File Encoding".

Comment: The default ISO 8559 should be fine and make sure you download them each week before the option to do so expires. It's worthwhile to check the first set you download the backups.